# Whenever I call a webservice path the class gets initialized

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I have a Restful webservice.

```
    @Path("/attributes")
    class A
    {
     MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection();
     @Path("getappslist")
     function B()
     {
       //query to create temp table here
     }
     @Path("getfilteredapps")
     function C()
     {
       //trying to access temp table
     }
    }
```

The issue is I am creating a temp table inside the method B of class A. Now when I try to call method C of class A by using the path /attributes from UI the class A is getting initialized every time and so a new MySql connection is getting established. Hence I couldn't access the temp table in method C. Is there a way that I can avoid this from happening?

I also heard about heap tables but I couldn't get details online about how long it can exist. I just want a temp table which gets deleted after I sign out of the application. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: “and so a new MySql connection is getting established.”  Why?  Loading a Java class doesn't create a database connection.  Perhaps you should edit your question and show the actual code of your class, including static initialization blocks.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Actually I am establishing connection in the beginning of the class. PS my edit